# Own array sprintf variant

Tags: c, arrays, stack, printf

I've been trying to make my own variant of a sprintf but when I'm passing the first parameter it work and after that it's returning 0.000 and it doesn't work anymore, I don't know what I'm doing wrong after trying so many things.

```
void sprintf_own_variant() {
    char buf[1024];
    char t[1024];
    char* str;
    get_stack_string(0, &str);
    memcpy(buf, str, 1024);
    printf("size of str = %d\n", strlen(buf)); //debug
    printf("%s\n", buf);
    int len = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < get_stack_argc(); i++) {
        printf("%d [%s]\n", i, buf);
        //if(len >= 1023)
            //break;
        memset(t, '\0', 1024);
        memcpy(t, buf, strlen(buf));
        switch(get_stack_type(i)) {
            case TYPE_STRING: {
                char* tmp;
                get_stack_string(i, &tmp);
                memset(buf, '\0', 1024);
                len += sprintf(buf, t, tmp);
            }
            break;

            case TYPE_INT: {
                int tmp;
                get_stack_int(i, &tmp);
                memset(buf, '\0', 1024);
                len += sprintf(buf, t, tmp);
            }
            break;

            case TYPE_FLOAT: {
                float tmp;
                get_stack_float(i, &tmp);
                memset(buf, '\0', 1024);
                len += sprintf(buf, t, tmp);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    add_stack_string(buf);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the error is in `get_stack_string`.  Why doesn't your function take any parameters?

Comment: What does `char *str` point to during the memcpy.

Comment: @tesseract: `get_stack_string(0, &str);` appears to retrieve a `char*` from the stack and assign it to the `str` variable.  Presumably `get_stack_argc()` retrieves the total number of parameters, and `get_stack_string(i, &tmp);` retrieves parameter `i` as a `char*` into `tmp`.

Comment: `sprintf(buf, t, tmp);` for each parameter... That's going to be undefined behavior any way you cut it.  The first time you call it, it will fill all but the first specifier with random data.  You got _lucky_ if all it did was replace those with zeros.

Comment: Why don't you do it the same as in stdlib? `int sprintf_own_variant(char *buff, int size, char *fmt, ...);`. Notice the size argument, without it this function presents a buffer overflow risk in most cases.

Comment: Because the "stack" where I'm getting the parameters from can't be called like that as a function. It's for a scripting language for a game where it's called like sprintf("test %d %f %s", 1, 1.2, "string"); which then goes through compiling for that scripting and then goes to bytecode where each variable is on the stack.